# Wicket: How to show Javascript dialog when Form.MultiPart(true)

Tags: javascript, wicket

When I try to upload file in Wicket I've got the following exception:

```
"ERROR org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.logRuntimeException(RequestCycle.java:1529) - ServletRequest does not contain multipart content. One possible solution is to explicitly call Form.setMultipart(true), Wicket tries its best to auto-detect multipart forms but there are certain situation where it cannot.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ServletRequest does not contain multipart content. One possible solution is to explicitly call Form.setMultipart(true), Wicket tries its best to auto-detect multipart forms but there are certain situation where it cannot.
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.MultipartServletWebRequest.<init>(MultipartServletWebRequest.java:113)..."
```

However, when I set `form.MultiPart(true)` I can't get Javascript dialog by using:

```
target.appendJavascript("Some Message");
```

Does somebody know how to use Javascript when `Form.Multipart(true)`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call the alert dialog as a response for an ajax request, you can use the `appendJavascript()` method (the argument is javascript code, not a simple string, like the code you posted):

```
target.appendJavaScript("alert('Some message');");
```

If you want to call the alert when the page loads, you could use a behavior:

```
add(new AbstractBehavior() { // or Behavior, on Wicket 1.5
    @Override
    public void renderHead(Component component, IHeaderResponse response) {
        response.renderOnLoadJavaScript("alert('Some message');");
    }
});
```

It's also possible use a Label, and render directly to a <script> tag. Just remember to call `setEscapeModelStrings(false)`:

```
add(new Label("alert", "alert('Some message');").setEscapeModelStrings(false));
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" wicket:id="alert"></script>
```

Comment: I want to call the alert in the end onSubmit() method of the AjaxButton. Can you, please, tell me how to use the code above in this case? I've tried to use it, but there were the errors...

Comment: just call `target.appendJavaScript("alert('Some message');");` inside the `AjaxButton.onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target)` method.

Comment: I've tried to call target.appendJavaScript("alert('Some message';"); inside the AjaxButton.onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) method when form.MultiPart(false) and it works (the dialog has been shown). But, when I've put form.MultiPart(true), the code doesn't work (the dialog hasn't been shown). It must be form.MultiPart(true) in order to use the upload functionality, but I don't know how to use JavaScript in that case...